# Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime' not found

Tags: php, mongodb

When trying to run this PHP piece of code

```
$document = [
   'username' => $_POST["username"],
   'email' => $_POST["email"],
   'hash_pwd' => password_hash(genereNouveauPwd(), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
   'tsCreation' => new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("midnight") * 1000),
];
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime' not found

I've tried to insert the line `extension=mongodb.so` in php.ini but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I had not configured PHP with mongodb (writing `extension=mongodb.so` in php.ini was clearly not enough : https://websiteforstudents.com/install-mongodb-with-apache2-php-7-2-support-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, what worked on Ubuntu localhost doesn't work on my Debian server and I have again the problem of "Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime' not found".

Sorry to spam with useless messages but I can't delete my former message.

Would it help if I wrote the procedure I followed to install MongoDB on the server ?